Prevent iFrame from opening in a new tab/window
I'm SUUUUPER new to this, so I really hope this isn't a stupid question...
Anyway, I'm using cURL and some PHP to embed an interactive activity in my website from this other website.
If it helps, I'm trying to embed an interactive activity that assesses the user's knowledge of different History Topics. The avatar will ask History questions, and people can record their answers, and in the end they get a detailed report of their knowledge of History. It's just a fun activity.
The person that provided us with this technology, gave us full permission to hide any references to their domain/website throughout our pages. The issue is that:

When people click ''open iFrame in new tab/window'' they get redirected to their website
When people click ''view detailed report'' they get redirected to their website

As I said, I really want to keep everything on our website, and I want to prevent people from ''spying on us'' and finding out what technology we're using to run this fun activity. I want it to keep it fully on-brand.
Can any of you please help me out?
Haven't really tried any remedies to this yet... I'm a total noob

You can't really "hide" anything you send over the internet to a client web browser.

I don't think there's any way to do what you want. You can use file_get_contents() to download the web site's HTML, and embed that directly into your page. But that won't work if it has any references back to their own site (like image links, script and CSS tags) using relative URLs.

If the links point to the original domain, and you don't control those links, then there's not a lot you can do except ask whoever controls them if there's a way they can be altered. The details provide here are too vague for us to suggest much, tbh. See [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue.

you have to fetch content of the  remote link and display on your  own web page. for the links you have to manually parse the dom elements and links and bind javascript click events on it to open the link within  your page . this is how proxy websites work. try to visit any website using  proxy service like zendproxy you will get the idea.

I would see if there is some sort of server side API you could use to interact with this 3rd party service.
